# The django-markdown-bootstrap-widget is not showing properly

Tags: django, markdown, django-widget

I am django beginner and I have the following Problem. I want to define a model and us this model to generate a form with the markdown-widget. https://github.com/MSA-Argentina/django-bootstrap-markdown

**Model**

```
class ThesisAnmeldung(models.Model):
    forschungsfrage = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.forschungsfrage
```

**Form**

```
class Thesis(ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget= MarkdownEditor(attrs={'id': 'content','height': 150, } ))
    name2 = forms.CharField(widget= MarkdownEditor(attrs={'id': 'content2','height': 150, } ))#
    class Meta:
        model = ThesisAnmeldung
        fields = ('forschungsfrage',)
        widgets = {'name': MarkdownEditor(attrs={'id': 'content3','height': 150, } ) , }
```

**Problem**
`name`  and `name2` are displayed correctly with the markdown-editor. 
Only the third field `forschungsfrage` shows the problem. i can only see a small standard textbox. It seems like the markdown-widget is not used. Is there any solution for this problem?

[**Picture**](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/17302959/14015343/80e9e708-f1b8-11e5-9a7f-300440461452.PNG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you set `forschungsfrage` to use markdown? You may overwrite that field in form as well.

```
class Thesis(ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget= MarkdownEditor(attrs={'id': 'content','height': 150, } ))
    name2 = forms.CharField(widget= MarkdownEditor(attrs={'id': 'content2','height': 150, } ))#
    forschungsfrage = forms.CharField(widget= MarkdownEditor(attrs={'id': 'forschungsfrage','height': 150, } ))

    class Meta:
        model = ThesisAnmeldung
        fields = ('forschungsfrage',)
```